# Generate a matrix using a given matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have matrix `A` size `M x N` where general element is `a_{i,j}`. I want matrix `B` size `M x N` where general element `b_{i,j}` generates such that `a_{i,j}` divided by sum of other elements of the same column (`j`-th column).

E.g.,  if `A` size `3 x 2`, then `b_{2,1}=a_{2,1}/(a_{1,1}+a_{1,3})`.

Can someone help me to write this in Matlab if `A=randn(M,N)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have MATLAB R2016b  / Octave you can do:

```
b = a ./ (sum(a) - a);
```

else you can use `bsxfun` :

```
b = a ./ bsxfun(@minus, sum(a), a);
```

I applied (in Octave) some timing on my answer and on the solution provoided by @MadPhysicist

```
a=rand(3000,2000);

disp('-------USING EYE----')
tic
x = size(a) ;
c = ~eye(x(1)) * a;
 a ./ c;
toc


disp('-------USING BSXFUN-')
tic
a ./ (sum(a) - a);
toc
```

Here is the result:

```
-------USING EYE----
Elapsed time is 0.454791 seconds.
-------USING BSXFUN-
Elapsed time is 0.0998709 seconds.
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to generate a matrix of divisors, then do an elementwise division. The elements for the divisor can be summed by premultiplying `a` by a boolean-negated identity matrix with the same number of rows and columns as there are rows in `a`. Left multiplication is easier to do since you want to sum by column instead of the usual rows.

```
c = ~eye(size(a, 1)) * a
b = a ./ c
```

Comment: Does `c` have the same size as `a`? When I run this code, I get warning of size mismatched.

Comment: In my case, `a` is not a square matrix always.

Comment: Should do, I'm on mobile, so give me a couple of moments to verify something

Comment: a does not have to be square, but I does. I was making c square instead of making it the same size as a.

Comment: Thanks @MadPhysicist